# Can a magnetic field exert a force on a magnet directly?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was studying Feynman lectures on physics volume 2 Chapter 1 Electromagnetism.

This book explains that a magnetic field produced by the current in the wire exerts forces on the magnet.

My question is, is that possible?

Also, I can't understand that directions of both magnetic field and a force that it exerts are the same.

The link below is where I brought a figure 1-7 of the book.
http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html#Ch1-S1

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Electric field is in the same direction as the force on a +ve electric charge, so why shouldn't the magnetic field be in the same direction as the force on the N pole of a magnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were happy with this diagram and the direction of the force on the wire due to the magnet

[image]

then your diagram shows the Newton third law pair, the force on the magnet due to the wire.

Note that in your diagram the north pole of the magnet sits on a magnetic field line due to the wire.
The direction of the magnetic field line gives you the direction of the force on an (isolated) north pole.